# Default API Version

Tags: rally

How does the Rally Rest API determine which version of the API to use (if no version is explicitly defined in the RallyRestAPI.new call)?

Background: we were testing out something via the Ruby API recently (actually looking to see what the valid fields were for a story in a given workspace), and found that not all valid fields were being advertised via the API.  But if we explicitly defined the latest API version (1.31), then it worked ok.  From looking at this more closely, without explicitly defining the API version, I guess our interfaces assumed a default version (which for us was 1.17).

Answer (score 0):

The Rally Rest API will default to the most current version of the Webservices if the version is not expressed in the RallyRestAPI object.

You can explicitly express the API version you would like to use like this:

```
rally = RallyRestAPI.new(:username => "<your email>", 
                         :password => "your password",
                         :version => "1.31")
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Not specifying the version number appears to always give us rallyAPIMinor='17' (it defaulting to a fixed version may not necessarily be a bad thing, since I know that 1.31 uses different structures to 1.17, and our code would need some updates to work with these updated structures).  Perhaps it's that we're still on rally_rest_api gem V1.0.1 (and if this is the issue, then we could consider whether we should upgrade to the latest gem, and for now, change our code to specify V1.17 of the code)?